# How can I make a progress bar around rounded rectangular shape in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a progress bar similar to this one with jetpack compose by canvas, and I've made some Shape, but I'm having trouble implementing the progress section.
I add a shape in drawWithContent of Box
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA5iJ.png)

```
val path = Path()
path.moveTo(x = startOffset.x, y = startOffset.y)


path.addRoundRect(
    RoundRect(
        left = 0F,
        top = 0F,
        right = this.size.width,
        bottom = this.size.height,
        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 16.dp.toPx(), y = 16.dp.toPx())
    )
)



clipPath(
    path = path,
    clipOp = ClipOp.Intersect
) {

    drawPath(
        path = path,
        style = Stroke(5.dp.toPx(), 16.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round),
        brush = SolidColor(Color.Red),
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Q74121342() {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val strokeWidth = remember { with(density) { 2.dp.toPx() } } // Convert to px for much needed stroke width

    val rotateTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val rotateAnimateValue = rotateTransition.animateValue(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 360f,
        typeConverter = Float.VectorConverter,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 1000,
                easing = LinearEasing
            ),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        )
    ) // Creating infinite animation. You can replace with finitive one and indicate current progress outside of composable

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(96.dp)
            .padding(2.dp)
            .drawBehind {
                rotate(
                    degrees = rotateAnimateValue.value
                ) {
                    drawArc(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        startAngle = 0f,
                        sweepAngle = 180f,
                        useCenter = false,
                        style = Stroke(
                            width = strokeWidth,
                            cap = StrokeCap.Round,
                            join = StrokeJoin.Round,
                        )
                    ) // Can be replaced with path but don't forget change image shape
                }
            } // Applying our custom paint
            .padding(2.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape), // Crop original image to much circle shape
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.img_profile),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )
}
```

You can see the demo on [gist](https://gist.github.com/SkyfaceD/06711e6d0a96c4dad06b700c4621cafe)